# can't see task running while in debugging window - visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, debugging, asynchronous, task, visual-studio-2019

I'm desperately trying to see while debugging my tasks that are running. I've opened the debugging task window but nothing shows. I've search on google but no success on this specific issue.

I'm using visual studio 2019 community edition. Console project .netcore 3.1

[image]

I've also enabled "use managed compatibility mode" but had no success.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the latest version of visual studio ?

Comment: @Afshin yes 2019, updated last month 16.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I tried your code in my side and did not face the issue as you described. So I suspect there is something wrong with your VS IDE.

[image]

So please follow the below steps to troubleshoot the issue:

**Suggestion**

**1)** disable any third party vs extensions under Extensions-->Manage Extensions to check if any other vs extensions block it.

**2)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder

**3)** reset all vs settings under `Tools`--> `Import and Export Settings`-->`Reset All Settings` and before you it, you could make a backup of your settings.

**4)** run `devenv /safemode` or `devenv /ResetSkipPkgs` under [Developer Command Prompt for VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) to start a pure VS. Then, open your project on it to test whether the issue persists.

**5)** create a new console project to test whether the issue happens on the new one.

**6)** [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it since the latest version `16.7` is released.

Comment: Don't know what of the above step/s fixed it but now it works. Was nearly there to format the system. Thanks